# button click itself many times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make a button for editing a post and after first edit I want to be able to edit the post again and again by pressing the button and I achieved this by calling the function again ( function1 ). The problem is the program somehow remember every press(I think) and every time I edit a post(without refreshing page) the program call my function(function1) for every button press I've done before..I will show in pictures.

Here are 3 pictures: [images]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwtSy.jpg).

The first one is when I edit first time, the second one after second edit, and the third one is after I edited my post 2 more times,
That notify show me when the function is called and those function chain from script is called how many times i press the Edit button..
That's it..sry for long post, I hope someone can find the bug.

I expect to edit a post how many times I want, without function1 running  for every press on Edit button I am making; I am begginer with JS, i used just for one week and now I am stuck.

P.S i am using codeigniter php framework for backend

```
<?php foreach ($exit as $a)
    { if( $a['endpoint_id'] === $id)
    { ?>
    <ul class=" list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item col-md-12" style="display: inline;" id="urllist<?php echo $a['id']?>" > 
            <div id="showUrl<?php echo $a['id'];?>" style="display:block" data-myValue="<?php echo $a['exit_url'];?>">             
                <p id="urlText<?php echo $a['id'];?>" > <?php echo $a['exit_url']; echo PHP_EOL; ?> </p> 
             </div>
            <div style="margin-right:1px;" id="Div<?php echo $a['id'];?>" >
                 <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $a['id'] ?> id='<?php echo $a['id'];?>'>
                 <button onclick="function1(<?php echo $a['id']; ?>); " class="btn btn-primary" id="btn<?php echo $a['id']?>" >Edit</button> 
                 <button onclick="function2(<?php echo $a['id']; ?>)" class="btn btn-primary" > Delete </button> 

            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
<?php 
    }   
} ?>

function function1(id) {

        //$("#btn"+id).prop("onclick",null); //removing onclick event for  avoiding the bug :'()

        if($("#update_url"+id).length) {
            $("#update_url"+id).show();
            $("#submit_update"+id).show();
        }
         else {
            $("#Div"+id).append($('<input type="text">').attr('id',"update_url"+id).attr('value',$("#showUrl"+id).attr('data-myValue'))); //make input text
            $("#Div"+id).append($('<input type="submit">').attr('value','Update').attr('id','submit_update'+id)); //make input submit and apend them      
         }

        $("#submit_update"+id).click(function() {
            update_url(id);
       });    
    }

//sending updated url to controller(db)
function update_url(id) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var deca =  $("#update_url"+id).val();

    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:  "<?php echo base_url(); ?>endpoint/update_url1",
             data: 'value1='+deca+'&value2='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $.notify("Update successfully","success");
                $("#submit_update"+id).click(show_update_url(id));
                $("#submit_update"+id).hide();
                $("#update_url"+id).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    }

//show updated exit url after edit press
function show_update_url(id) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>endpoint/new_url/"+id,
                success : function(text)
                {
                    if($("#phehe"+id).length) {
                        $("#phehe"+id).hide();
                    }

                    //alert(text);
                    $("#Div"+id).prepend($('<p>'+text+'</p>').attr('id','phehe'+id));

                }
            });
        });
        $("#urlText"+id).css("display","none");
    }
```

Comment: onclick is not a prop

Comment: and what does that mean?

Comment: @Hyperion it means that is not a valid property, you could probably use `.unbind()` to unbind the click event before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery event binding are appended to an event each time `.click(...)` or `.on(...)` is used. In function1(), you are binding the click events on the `"#submit_update"+id` element every time the function is called by your edit button. The quick fix would be the unbind the event in function1() by calling `$("#submit_update"+id).off('click')`.

Another way would be to bind the events outside of the event stack itself. Basically you don't want to bind new events within events.

Something like this. This is not tested.

```
<?php foreach ($exit as $a)
    { if( $a['endpoint_id'] === $id)
    { ?>
    <ul class=" list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item col-md-12" style="display: inline;" id="urllist<?php echo $a['id']?>" > 
            <div id="showUrl<?php echo $a['id'];?>" style="display:block" data-myValue="<?php echo $a['exit_url'];?>">             
                <p id="urlText<?php echo $a['id'];?>" > <?php echo $a['exit_url']; echo PHP_EOL; ?> </p> 
             </div>
            <div style="margin-right:1px;" id="Div<?php echo $a['id'];?>" >
                 <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $a['id'] ?> id='<?php echo $a['id'];?>'>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" data-id="?php echo $a['id']?>" id="btn<?php echo $a['id']?>" >Edit</button> 
                 <button onclick="function2(<?php echo $a['id']; ?>)" class="btn btn-primary" > Delete </button> 

            </div>

         </li>
    </ul>
<?php 
    }   
} ?>


$('.btn-edit').click(function() {
    const id = $(this).data('id');

    if($("#update_url"+id).length) {
            $("#update_url"+id).show();
            $("#submit_update"+id).show();
        }
         else {
            $("#Div"+id).append($('<input type="text">').attr('id',"update_url"+id).attr('value',$("#showUrl"+id).attr('data-myValue'))); //make input text
            $("#Div"+id).append($('<input type="submit">').class('btn-update').attr('value','Update').attr('id','submit_update'+id).data('id', id); //make input submit and apend them      
         }
});

$('.btn-update').on('click', function() {
    const id = $(this).data('id');

    update_url(id);
});

function update_url(id) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var deca =  $("#update_url"+id).val();

    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:  "<?php echo base_url(); ?>endpoint/update_url1",
             data: 'value1='+deca+'&value2='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $.notify("Update successfully","success");

                show_update_url(id);

                $("#submit_update"+id).hide();
                $("#update_url"+id).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    }

//show updated exit url after edit press
function show_update_url(id) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>endpoint/new_url/"+id,
                success : function(text)
                {
                    if($("#phehe"+id).length) {
                        $("#phehe"+id).hide();
                    }

                    //alert(text);
                    $("#Div"+id).prepend($('<p>'+text+'</p>').attr('id','phehe'+id));

                }
            });
        });
        $("#urlText"+id).css("display","none");
    }
```

Comment: I have made the changes but it acts the same... when I try to edit second time, third time without refreshing the page those functions responsible with showing the input for edit and update_url,show_update_url run twice, respectively three times. However the problem is bcs my button keeps "reminding"  all presses and run..is this the right behavior?